# Changing the Header of urllib2 to get different search results on google

Tags: python, python-requests, http-headers, urllib2, google-search

Can I change the header on a google query to get the results I would get for mobile?

I'm trying to get different results on google according to different headers in the library `urllib2` or `requests`. I use `beautifulsoup` to parse the results.

For example I use this header to simulate the **Desktop** results:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/ 58.0.3029.81 Safari/537.36
```

my **mobile** header would be this

```
Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 9_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/601.1.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/9.0 Mobile/13B137 Safari/601.1
```

The question is now:

Is this possible or will google recognize, that I'm not using a phone to get the google results? I don't get different results. I use this code to just try:

```
import requests
headers_mobile = { 'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 9_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/601.1.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/9.0 Mobile/13B137 Safari/601.1'}
link = 'https://www.google.com/search?q=testseite&num=22&hl=de'
B_response = requests.get(link, headers=headers_mobile)
for i in B_response:
    print(i)
```

Comment: There isn't any question stated clearly in the first three paragraphs, you need to restate this, move the question up the top. I think you mean *"Can I change the header on a google query to get the results I would get for mobile?"* Also suggest you search for "mobile and desktop SEO".

Comment: Thanks for that, I put the question in the first paragraph!

Comment: It is against Google's [Webmaster Guidelines](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/guidelines/webmaster-guidelines) and [terms of service](https://policies.google.com/terms/archive/20020906?hl=en) to submit programmatic search queries.  Running this code against Google is likely to cause Google to show captcha for searches from your IP address.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible. [List of mobile `user-agents`](https://developers.whatismybrowser.com/useragents/explore/hardware_type_specific/mobile/7).

But instead of iterating over `requests.get()` result, you need to pass it to `BeautifulSoup` object, and then select a certain element (*container with data*) and iterate over it.

```py
# container with mobile layout data
for mobile_result in soup.select('.xNRXGe'):
  title = mobile_result.select_one('.q8U8x').text
  link = mobile_result.select_one('a.C8nzq')['href']
  snippet = mobile_result.select_one('.VwiC3b').text
```

---

Code and [example in the online IDE](https://replit.com/@DimitryZub1/Google-Scrape-Title-Description-Linkpythonbs4#bs4_results.py):

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests, lxml

headers = {
    'User-agent':
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 7.0; LGMP260) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.93 Mobile Safari/537.36'
}

params = {
  'q': 'how to create minecraft server',
  'gl': 'us',                             # country to search from
  'hl': 'en',                             # language
}

html = requests.get('https://www.google.com/search', headers=headers, params=params)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'lxml')

for mobile_result in soup.select('.xNRXGe'):
  title = mobile_result.select_one('.q8U8x').text
  link = mobile_result.select_one('a.C8nzq')['href']
  snippet = mobile_result.select_one('.VwiC3b').text
  print(title, link, snippet, sep='\n')

-----------
'''
How to Setup a Minecraft: Java Edition Server – Home
https://help.minecraft.net/hc/en-us/articles/360058525452-How-to-Setup-a-Minecraft-Java-Edition-Server
How to Setup a Minecraft: Java Edition Server · Go to this website and download the minecraft_server. · After you have downloaded it, make a folder on your ...
Minecraft Server Download
https://www.minecraft.net/en-us/download/server
Download the Minecraft: Java Edition server. Want to set up a multiplayer server? · Download minecraft_server.1.17.1.jar and run it with the following command:.
# other results
'''
```

---

Alternatively, you can achieve the same thing by using [Google Organic Results API](https://serpapi.com/organic-results) from SerpApi. It's a paid API with a free plan. Check out the [playground](https://serpapi.com/playground?q=how%20to%20create%20minecraft%20server&location=United%20States&gl=us&hl=en&device=mobile).

The difference in your case is that you don't have to figure out things (*well, you have to, but it's a much more straightforward process*), don't have to maintain the parser over time, and iterate over structured JSON instead.

Code to integrate:

```py
import os
from serpapi import GoogleSearch

params = {
  "api_key": os.getenv("API_KEY"),
  "engine": "google",
  "q": "how to create minecraft server",
  "hl": "en",
  "gl": "us",
  "device": "mobile"  # mobile results
}

search = GoogleSearch(params)
results = search.get_dict()

for result in results["organic_results"]:
  print(result['title'])
  print(result['link'])

-----------
'''
How to Setup a Minecraft: Java Edition Server – Home
https://help.minecraft.net/hc/en-us/articles/360058525452-How-to-Setup-a-Minecraft-Java-Edition-Server
How to Setup a Minecraft: Java Edition Server · Go to this website and download the minecraft_server. · After you have downloaded it, make a folder on your ...
Minecraft Server Download
https://www.minecraft.net/en-us/download/server
Download the Minecraft: Java Edition server. Want to set up a multiplayer server? · Download minecraft_server.1.17.1.jar and run it with the following command:.
# other results
'''
```

> Disclaimer, I work for SerpApi.